# htaccess too many redirects create infinite loop?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, infinite-loop

I'm stuck in what appears to be an infinite redirecting loop, caused by rewrite conditions in my htaccess file.

The goal was first to get rid of the .php extension, which worked.

Then I wanted to rewrite **site.com/profile?user=username** to **site.com/username**, which also worked.

But now, only site.com/username works. All other urls are stuck in a loop *'too many redirects occurred trying to open...'* **except** if I write the .php extension again. Then the page opens.

How can I cumulate both rewrite rules and have them both work together?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Any help much appreciated, as I really do not understand this...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is your URL is profile.php or profile?

Comment: Both work thanks to the .php rewrite rule. Basically if I get rid of **RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L]** then all urls work without the .php extension (which I need), but with it, no urls work without the .php extension. 

Could the problem be **^([^/]*)$** and **^([^\.]+)$** somewhere?